# 0以外の判定をしたい。浮動小数点型のDBカラムからデータを取得した場合

Tags: javascript, php

**前提**
・浮動小数点型のDBカラムに、「-12.656322」「987.732849」「0.000000」などの数値が入っています

---

**目的**
・PHPでデータ取得後、JSで「0ではない判定」を行いたい

---

**Q1**
・DBより「0.000000」を取得後、PHPからjsへ渡すと、「0」になってしまいます
・なぜでしょうか？
・気にする必要はない？

```
 var hoge = <?php echo $hoge; ?>;
 console.log(hoge); //0
```

**Q2**
・条件分岐する際、「0」と「0.000000」を考慮する必要はあるでしょうか？
・どちらもNumber型？
・「==」と「===」の違い？

・とりあえず、下記にしたのですが、

```
if(hoge != 0){}
```

普通はどう書くのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1
javascript では数値はいわゆる浮動小数型です。
他の言語のように整数型というのがありません。
なので

```
var hoge = 0.00000;
var hoge = 0.0;
var hoge = 0;
```

はどれも同じ意味になります。

Q2
もしもPHPで０にならない微量な数値があったとしても
文字列として0.00000のような０を意味する文字列になって
（微量な数値があったとしても、ここでその情報は失われる)
javascriptでそれは０になりますから
「0」と「0.000000」(0.000000には微量な数値があるが表現上０に見える)を考慮する必要はありません。
つまり、
`if(hoge != 0){…}`
で問題無いです。

---

一般には浮動小数の計算の結果理論的には０になるはずであっても、
計算誤差や表現誤差によって正確には０でないような場合には
`if(-0.01 < hoge && hoge < 0.01){…}`
のような範囲で調べるようなことが必要な場合があります。

Comment: ＞どれも同じ意味になります。初めて知りました。これまで「浮動小数型」をほとんど使用したことがなかったため、大変参考になりました